# Prove $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3K_i+2}{2K_i+1}$ can never be a power of $2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a finite set of numbers $K_i \in \mathbb N$.

Can we prove that the product $$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3K_i+2}{2K_i+1}$$

can never be equal a power of $2$?

As you can see, each term is between $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{5}{3}$. The greater $K_i$, the closer it is to $\frac{3}{2}$. Ratio between exact power or $\frac{3}{2}$ and the next greater power of $2$ places the constraint on $K_i$ values: the lowest $K_i$ cannot exceed certain value. For example, for products up to $2000$ terms, the biggest lowest value of $K_i$ was found to be for $1636$ terms, and it is $291643$.

The value would be a power of $2$ if all factors of the numerator and the denominator, except of $2$s in the numerator, completely canceled each other. Note that the denominator is always odd. It appears that there's no set of $K_i$ to make such a product equal to a power of $2$.

But can it be proven?

Comment: We must stipulate $n\ge1$, since an empty product is $2^0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not true. For instance, define $\mathcal K:=\{5,6,8,24,27,32,41,47,69,92\}$. Then we have,
$$\prod_{i\in\mathcal K}\frac{3i+2}{2i+1}=2^6.$$

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice counter-example.

Comment: How did you obtain this counter example?